# Sorting varchar fields for mysql database

Tags: mysql

Trying to sort the following TEAM_TOTAL Column Desc

```
MATCHID     TEAM_TOTAL        
 ----------  ----------------- 
 573         Total   112       
 573         Total  2 for  115 
 574         Total  9 for  97  
 574         Total  2 for  100 
 575         Total  9 for  129 
 575         Total  9 for  101 
 576         Total  4 for  191 
 576         Total  9 for  160 
 577         Total  8 for  157 
 577         Total  7 for  137 
 578         Total  6 for  193 
 578         Total   119
```

But the problem is TEAM_TOTAL is varchar, is there a way with query alone I can get the results in the sorted desc order.
More over there is a text as well in that column. I am running out of ideas to get this up

Result should have beeen like the below Result Set

```
   MATCHID     TEAM_TOTAL        
  ----------  ----------------- 
  578         Total  6 for  193
  576         Total  4 for  191  
  576         Total  9 for  160 
  577         Total  8 for  157 
  577         Total  7 for  137
  575         Total  9 for  129
  578         Total   119 
  573         Total  2 for  115 
   573         Total   112 
  575         Total  9 for  101
  574         Total  2 for  100
  574         Total  9 for  97
```

Comment: try `select * from tableName ORDER BY TEAM_TOTAL`

Comment: How this column `Team_TOTAL` is populated from your query, Can you post it.

Comment: @FahimParkar, `Team_TOTAL` is a `varchar` column, i.e will be sorted alphapitacally, but the OP want it to be sorted by the number after the for keywoard.

Comment: Not to be a jerk... but the right answer here is to make your data sane.

Comment: @ Fahim Parkar  It wont work as its a varchar, it tries to sort the alphabetically

Comment: @MGA : Gotcha!!! My mistake... Now we would need to know Team_TOTAL is populated.... Right question!!!

Comment: I understand the sorting part... but why did you remove `119`??

Comment: @MGA, we get the data in csv format and we just the dump in those tables

Comment: @ Mosty Mostacho , sorry i missed out that entry while updating in the SOF, will update in the question in little while

Comment: @gmhk, then you can `ORDER BY MID(TEAM_TOTAL, pos, len)` and cast it to int, but the problem will be with the data row `Total 112`.

Comment: @MGA, that was the challenge I have

Comment: @gmhk, Not a challenge you should test the length of the `TEAM_TOTAL` then castomize the `pos` and `len` to match the two different cases and then cast it to int, but take care of the length of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
select * from t
order by substring(
    team_total, locate('for', team_total) + 
        if(locate('for', team_total) > 0, 4, 7))+0 desc
```

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/82086/1).

Comment: Thank You so much It worked really superb, You are the SQL GURU

Answer (score 0):

Try to extract the integer (string after the last space):

```
-- 'Total 112' - extracts 112
SELECT SUBSTRING('Total  112', LENGTH('Total  112') - LOCATE(' ', REVERSE('Total  112'))); 

-- 'Total  6 for  193' - extracts 193
SELECT SUBSTRING('Total  6 for  193', LENGTH('Total  6 for  193') - LOCATE(' ', REVERSE('Total  6 for  193')));
```

Now, you can convert that string to a number and then order by it.

```
SELECT * FROM teams
ORDER BY
CAST(SUBSTRING(TEAM_TOTAL, LENGTH(TEAM_TOTAL) - LOCATE(' ', REVERSE(TEAM_TOTAL))) AS INT) DESC
```